# can anyone explain this while control structure?

Tags: bash, while-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
number=0
while [ "$number" -lt 10 ]
do
    echo -n "$number"
    ((number +=1))
done
echo
```

Can anyone explain why `$` is not needed in `((number += 1))`?

Comment: What part don't you understand? It's as simple as `while` loops get.

Comment: Just read it as English, it does exactly what that says.

Comment: ** ((number +=1))**  here why number is not given with $

Comment: Inside `(( ... ))` it recognizes variables automatically.

Comment: From [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic): _Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use shell arithmetic with `(( ... ))`, the `$` before variables is optional. Since this is just used for arithmetic, strings are not allowed, so any unquoted token that isn't a number or operator is treated as a variable. The section of the Bash Manual on [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) explains:

> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is performed before the expression is evaluated. Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.